# How to use python flask to read/write from/to pyswip?

Tags: python, python-2.7, prolog, swi-prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

I was trying to use pyswip to create a Q&A (interactive user) python swi-prolog program and I couldn't find a good way to read/write from/to pyswip using python flask. The app is originally a web application and I'm using flask to run the python code.

I have a function that asks a question to the user defined as follows:

```
def question(Question):
  print 'Does it have the following attributes: ', Question,'?'
  Response = raw_input()
  if Response == 'yes' or Response == 'y':
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

The question function is defined as a foreign function with arity 1  so in prolog I have this:

```
registerForeign(question,name='ask', arity=1)
prolog.assertz("verify(S) :- (yes(S) -> true ;(no(S) -> fail ;(ask(S) -> assert(yes(S)); assert(no(S)), fail)))")
```

Note `ask(S)` in the `assertz` that is the call to the question function I have, now I need to change the arity of question function to 2:

```
registerForeign(question,name='ask', arity=2) 
question(Question, userInput)
```

where `userInput` is the python `raw_input` parser that should read the user's input and if you look at the question function you will notice that it used to be done inside the function itself.

Any thoughts on how I can change the prolog part accordingly?